# How not inherit class QGraphicsTextItem and implement class UTextItem?

Tags: qt

How not inherit class QGraphicsTextItem and implement class UTextItem ,in Qt.

I don't need code similar to below

```
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>

class UTextItem: public QGraphicsTextItem 
{ 
public:
 UTextItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr);
}
```

I need code similar to below，I need code similar to below, and not the text drawn by the drawText function, because the drawn string will lose detail when scaled.

```
#include <QGraphicsItem>
class UTextItem: public QGraphicsItem 
{ 
public: 
 UTextItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr);
 void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget); 
}
```

Because my current requirement is to have a TextItem that can be deformed, flipped horizontally and vertically, and the scaling of drawText will be distorted, so I can't use this method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By reading the source code, I found the scaling problem solution myself.

```
void UTextItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
        QFont font;
        font.setPixelSize(0.75 * qMin(boundingRect().width(), boundingRect().height()));

        painter->save();
        painter->setFont(font);
        painter->drawText(boundingRect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "hello world");
        painter->restore();
    
}
```